# How to get an extra client connection (nestjs-ioredis)

Tags: redis, nestjs, ioredis

I'm using Redis on my Nestjs project. Therefor I'm making use of the package [svtslv/nestjs-ioredis](https://github.com/svtslv/nestjs-ioredis)

I'm not very experienced yet in Nestjs (and Typescript). But I try to figure out how to get a second client connection (to the same database) because I want to work with a subscriber and publisher.

Something like next Node-implementation done in Nestjs when using this Nest-package:

```
const Redis = require("ioredis");
const redis = new Redis();
const pub = new Redis();
redis.subscribe("news", "music", (err, count) => {
  // Now we are subscribed to both the 'news' and 'music' channels.
  // `count` represents the number of channels we are currently subscribed to.

  pub.publish("news", "Hello world!");
  pub.publish("music", "Hello again!");
});

redis.on("message", (channel, message) => {
  // Receive message Hello world! from channel news
  // Receive message Hello again! from channel music
  console.log("Receive message %s from channel %s", message, channel);
});

// There's also an event called 'messageBuffer', which is the same as 'message' except
// it returns buffers instead of strings.
redis.on("messageBuffer", (channel, message) => {
  // Both `channel` and `message` are buffers.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RedisModule.forRoot({}, 'secondConnection')
@InjectRedis('secondConnection') private readonly redis: Redis
```

(Big thank you to the developer himself of this project)